# Webpart feature not adding Description

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, web-parts, moss

I am adding a webpart to the webpart gallery as part of a feature within a solution.

When the webpart is added to the gallery, the webparts Description field is being overwritten by an empty string.

I have added a description to everywhere I can think of, including:

1. The webpart itself. myWebpart.webpart `<property name="Description" type="string">my description</property>`
2. The feature.xml `Description="mywebpart description"`
3. The feature.xml `<Property Key="Description" Value="mywebpart description"></Property>`
4. The webpartManifest.xml (specified in the feature) `<File ...><Property Name=Description" Value="mywebpart description">`

I have run out of ideas of where to put the description so it will appear in the Description field of the web part gallery when the solution is deployed.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following blog, it describes the whole process:
[Adding custom webparts in a Sharepoint Site Definition](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/nicksevens/archive/2007/11/23/adding-custom-webparts-in-a-sharepoint-site-definition.aspx)

Specially notice the custom property *TextToDisplay* (I think you've gone through all the other steps).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, all the steps were correct, except that the property name for the webpart was mis-spelt  as "**Decription**".

Doh

Comment: OK, I couldn't have helped with that :-)